# Finding Expectation using CDF

Tags: statistics, expected-value

$$F(x)=
\begin{cases}
\ 0 & \text{if $\ \ \ x<0$}\\
\ \dfrac{4}{9}& \text { if $\ \ \ 0 \le x<1$}\\
\ \dfrac{8}{9}& \text { if $\ \ \ 1 \le x<2$} \\
\ 1& \text { if $\ \ \  x\ge 2$}
\end{cases}
$$

I am trying to find out expectation using this $$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_0^\infty (1-F(x)) \mathrm{d}x$$
If I replace integral with the sum, I found this expectation:

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=(0)\left(1-\dfrac{4}{9}\right)+(1)\left(1-\dfrac{8}{9}\right)+ (2)(1-1)=\dfrac{1}{9}$$

But when I calculate via $$\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum x\Pr(X=x)=0\cdot \dfrac{4}{9}+1\cdot \dfrac{4}{9}+2\cdot \dfrac{1}{9}=\dfrac{6}{9}=\dfrac{2}{3}$$

Why am I getting different answer in first method I did. I should be getting $\dfrac{2}{3}$. Can anyone point out my mistake ?

Comment: Your integral of $1-F(x)$ is totally wrong, you should have 1 multiplying all three terms, giving $5/9+1/9=2/3$. The 1s in question are the lengths of the intervals where $F$ is constant; where those intervals are located does not get included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\mathbb E(X)=\int\limits_0^\infty (1-F(x)) dx = \int\limits_0^1 \left(1-\frac49\right)dx + \int\limits_1^2 \left(1-\frac89\right)dx = \frac59 \cdot 1+ \frac19\cdot 1 = \frac23.
$$
You can also draw a graph of $F(x)$ and find the area above the positive semi-axis between this function and the function equal to one.

[image: graph of the CDF]

Comment: Even for discrete probabilities we have to integrate ?  Don't we use summation for discrete probabilities.

Comment: Technically, integration and summation are the same thing. But your method would work if you notice the distribution function is right continuous.

Comment: Yes it is right continuous but can you tell me how will computations will work?

Comment: @orange I think you didnt get notification of my comment.